# Double authentication error with JWT Spring Security and Angular 12

Tags: angular, spring-security, jwt

I'm trying to get my JWT token from spring security. I can get it from postman, but when I'm making the request from angular, it opens a snackBar requesting credentials.

This is my login service:

```
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  url: string = `${environment.apiToken}`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  logIn(usuario: string, contrasena: string) {
    const body = `grant_type=password&username=${encodeURIComponent(usuario)}&password=${encodeURIComponent(contrasena)}`;

    console.log(btoa(environment.TOKEN_AUTH_USERNAME + ':' + environment.TOKEN_AUTH_PASSWORD));
    console.log(body);

    return this.http.post<any>(this.url, body, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(environment.TOKEN_AUTH_USERNAME + ':' + environment.TOKEN_AUTH_PASSWORD))
    });
  }

  logOut() {
    if (this.estaLogueado()) {
      let token = sessionStorage.getItem(environment.TOKEN_NAME);

      this.http.get(`${environment.HOST}/cerrarSesion/anular/${token}`).subscribe(() => {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      });
    }else{
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem(environment.TOKEN_NAME);
    return token !== null;
  }
}
```

I'm making requests by a proxy, this is my proxy.conf

```
{
    "/token": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel":"debug"
    }
}
```

This is the snackbar
[image: This is the snackbar]

When I'm checking the headers and body of the request made by angular, it's the same request from postman.

Authorization headers from angular
[image: Authorization headers from angular]

Body from angular
[image: Body from angular]

Authorization and headers from postman
[image: Authorization and headers from postman]

This is my application.properties in Spring

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false

spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/demo
!<-- Database Credentials -->
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin

!<-- Security -->
security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3
security.signing-key = MaYzkSjmkzPC57L
security.encoding-strength=256
security.security-realm= Spring Boot JWT
!<-- jwt -->
security.jwt.client-id=redsocialaappspring
security.jwt.client-secret=redsocial2021
security.jwt.grant-type=password
security.jwt.scope-read=read
security.jwt.scope-write=write
security.jwt.resource-ids=redsocialId
```

This is my securityConfig class

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.signing-key}")
    private String signingKey;

    @Value("${security.encoding-strength}")
    private Integer encodingStrength;

    @Value("${security.security-realm}")
    private String securityRealm;

    // Libreria para hashing
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt;

    // Obtiene usuarios, roles y claves de la aplicación
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    // Codificar las contraseñas por hashing
    @Bean
    public static BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEnconder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    // Obtener detalles del usuario por medio de una interfaz
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bcrypt);
    }

    // Comportamiento de la seguridad, al ser por servicios es stateless
    // Desactivamos tokens csrf -- veitando ataques js dentro de los formularios
    // Usamos jwt -Oauth
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .realmName(securityRealm)
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable();
    }

    // Instancia para crear tokens
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
        return converter;
    }

    // Guardado de tokens
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(this.dataSource);
    }

    // Acción primaria en ejecutarse
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setReuseRefreshToken(false);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

}
```

This is my resourceServerConfig class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ResourceServerTokenServices;

import com.example.demo.exception.AuthExceptionOwn;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{
    
    //Traemos la configuración de SecurityConfig
    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;
    
    @Value("${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
    private String resourceIds;
    
    //Creación de token y configuración de resourceIds
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception{
        resources.resourceId(resourceIds).tokenServices(tokenServices);
    }
    
    //URLs y metodos de proteccion
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthExceptionOwn())
        .and()
        .requestMatchers()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/amigos/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/usuarios/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/cerrarSesion/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/token/**").permitAll();
    }

}
```

This is my authorizationServer class

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancerChain;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;

//Elaboración del token
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Value("${security.jwt.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.jwt.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${security.jwt.grant-type}")
    private String grantType;
    
    @Value("${security.jwt.scope-read}")
    private String scopeRead;
    
    @Value("${security.jwt.scope-write}")
    private String scopeWrite;
    
    @Value("${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
    private String resourceIds;
    
    //Se trae la configuración
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt;
    
    //Grantype genera valores de acceso
    //Tiempo de vida del token
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception{
        configurer.inMemory().withClient(clientId).secret(bcrypt.encode(clientSecret))
        .authorizedGrantTypes(grantType).scopes(scopeRead, scopeWrite).resourceIds(resourceIds)
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(7200).refreshTokenValiditySeconds(0);
    }
    
    //Se genera la cadena de texto de jwt
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        
        enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
        .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, I'm calling /token twice at the end of my angular proxy

The proxy.conf.json endded up like this

```
{
    "/token": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080/oauth",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel":"debug"
    }
}
```

Thanks everybody for your help >:[.